# regex for a character pattern that is scattered throughout the text

Tags: python, regex

I'm a Python and regex noob.  I managed to get a full page of html source into the command line by the following statement.

```
print (driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')
```

Cool.  But there are some predictable strings in that text that I need to extract and store into an array.  The string pattern being looked for is, [4 numbers] followed by a [hyphen] followed by between 1 and 5 numbers, e.g.:

2013-80324 or 2013-03 but not 2013-832888

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=\D))\d{4}-\d{1,5}(?=\D|$)
```

- `?:` denotes a non capturing group
- `^` matches the pattern at start of string (though unlikely for HTML input)
- `$` mathces the pattern at the end of string
- `\d` denotes a digit `[0-9]` and `\D` a **non**-digit
- `{n}` is a quantifier for length `n`
- `{m,n}` quantifies a length of range `m` to `n` (both inclusive)

Comment: This can be written much simpler using [negative lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?<!\d)\d{4}-\d{1,5}(?!\d)`

Comment: @TimPietzcker thanks for sharing that. I didn't know about this subtle difference between `!\d` and `\D`. Matching the anchors as well certainly simplifies the regex more.